# Distribution of "yelp" for "yes"

Tags: vocabulary, variants, african-american-vernacular-english

I've recently come across two people online who consistently write "yelp" meaning "yes" or "yep" in chat. Due to anonymity and privacy, I don't know much about them. From their speech patterns I'm guessing they speak [AAVE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African-American_Vernacular_English), but I live in Australia and most of my exposure to AAVE comes from television. I'm not in a position where I can ask them about their backgrounds.

Has "yelp" been recorded as a variant of "yes" in certain people's speech? How widespread is this?

Comment: [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Yelp) doesn't seem to mention this definition.

Comment: "Yep" is a common word in US English, and has been in common use for my entire lifetime (70+ years).

Answer (score 2):

I think your intuition is correct. I searched Twitter and found some examples from people who (due to specific dialect features) most likely speak AAVE. They are apparently pretty scattered across the US:

- [A’laina.B](https://mobile.twitter.com/search?q=%40ShortcakeBad%20Yelp&src=typed_query), an entrepreneur from Atlanta, Georgia

  > Looking At Pics Of Your Boo & Like Yelp Dat Me
- [Trawood](https://mobile.twitter.com/search?q=%40_trawood%20yelp&src=typed_query&f=top), a hip hop (rap?) artist from Chicago, Illinois

  > "@[user]: you supposed to be the one I go to when my head hurts" yelp I sure Can Slow Down Dat ma'grain headache....
- [Big Deesh](https://mobile.twitter.com/search?q=%40keyonnea_%20yelp&src=typed_query) from Los Angeles, California

  > I need some good sex n a strong drink... Yelp dat will get me right LOL...

Possibly this is related to *welp* (well + p).

I'm not sure if "yelp" is spoken as well as written.

It's possible that "yelp" is used outside AAVE (either by imitation or independently) but my searches were geared towards finding AAVE speakers. I found many more (AAVE) examples, though it's not really possible to determine how frequently people use it from Twitter alone.

Answer (score 1):

I may don't know much about AAVE, but I do have English-speaking friends writing "yelp" or "yep" in chat. According to them, "yep" is a cooler way to say yes, and a more friendly/familiar one. Regarding "yelp", it's a contraction of both "help" and "yes", and they use it as a way to express their answers/comments to a supposedly not-so-good situation in a funny way.

Unfortunately, I can't confirm that it's the same kind of meaning in other contexts or for other people.

Comment: Hello, Louisa. I'd guess 'yep' is a widely-known corruption of 'yes' (along with 'yeah'), but 'yelp' is virtually unknown. Answers on ELU are far better if accompanied by supporting references. The occasional idiosyncrasies of individuals are far from standard, and off-topic on ELU.

Comment: Hello, Edwin. Thank you for warning me. I'm sorry for my lack of understanding... In the future, I won't post answers without proper supporting references.

Comment: This (your answer) is a good anecdotal comment. The snag is that there's a 50-rep hurdle to jump before new contributors can use _comment_s. This sadly cuts off some good comments as well as the rubbish it's intended to forestall.